# How do I get the cookieConsent nav to auto expand on mobile?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

**Background**

I have an ASP.Net Core v2.1 web application which has the CheckConsentNeeded flag set to true in startup.

```
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.SameSiteMode.None;
        });
```

I have a sign up form on the home page that uses [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] on the post action.

**Issue**

If someone tries to sign up before the cookies are accepted, they get the following error:

```
ERROR - ExceptionHandlerMiddleware - An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request. System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
```

**Requirement**

I want to auto expand the cookieConsent panel on a mobile until they accept cookies to make it more obvious they need to do this instead of them having to look by manually clicking the hamburger icon.

**Action Taken**

I can see the code in the _cookieConsentPartial gives me the flag I need (showBanner):

```
@{
    var consentFeature = Context.Features.Get<ITrackingConsentFeature>();
    var showBanner = !consentFeature?.CanTrack ?? false;
    var cookieString = consentFeature?.CreateConsentCookie();
}

@if (showBanner)
{
```

I was hoping I could add some JQuery code in here to add the class "in" to the .navbar-collapse selector.

```
$.when($.ready).then(function () {
        var $navBar = $(".navbar-collapse");
        if (!$navBar.hasClass("in")) {
            $navBar.addClass("in");
        }
    });
```

However, 2 things.

1. I can't use JQuery in the cookieConsentPartial because the partial is loaded higher up than the script files are.
2. If I run the JQuery script in the console after the page has loaded I get the menu rather than the cookieConsent content. The hamburger click toggle also stops working.

Can anyone suggest the best way to implement this requirement in Asp.Net Core 2.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come back to this, this morning and it turned out to be straight forward to implement in the end.

I just needed to add the "in" class to the navbar-collapse div beneath the navbar-header on the _cookieConsentPartial.

```
<div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#cookieConsent .navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle cookie consent banner</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
</div>
<div class="collapse **in** navbar-collapse">
    <p class="navbar-text">
        <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> We use our cookies and third party cookies to improve our services, obtain statistics, allow you to remember your login details, and to facilitate your interaction with social networks.
    </p>
    ...
```